# Create a new Google Cloud project using gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

As per the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init `gcloud init myproject` command does not work.

`google-cloud> gcloud init myproject
Initialized gcloud directory in [/Users/arungupta/workspaces/google-cloud/myproject/.gcloud].
Cloning [https://source.developers.google.com/p/myproject/r/default] into [default].
Cloning into '/Users/arungupta/workspaces/google-cloud/myproject/default'...
fatal: remote error: Repository not found.
You may need to create a repository for this project using the Source Code tab at https://console.developers.google.com
ERROR: Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/myproject/r/default', '/Users/arungupta/workspaces/google-cloud/myproject/default', '--config', 'credential.helper=gcloud.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 128
ERROR: Unable to initialize project [myproject], cleaning up [/Users/arungupta/workspaces/google-cloud/myproject].
ERROR: (gcloud.init) Unable to initialize project [myproject].`

Creating a project using `gcloud init minecraft-server --project minecraft-server-183` creates the project with the name `minecraft-server-183`.

The project so created is then not visible at https://console.developers.google.com/project.

What is the correct `gcloud` command to create a new project, without going to the console?

Comment: [`gcloud init` no longer takes a *project-name* argument](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init).  It just does general  setup for the current user including authentication.

Answer (score 8):

It is now possible with the [`gcloud alpha projects create` command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/projects/create).

For more information see: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/

Comment: Is there an ETA when this would be available?

Comment: There is no ETA at the moment. Currently the console is the only way to create a project, enable an API, and configure billing. (I work on the Cloud SDK team)

Comment: I updated my answer. Unfortunately it is only available to approved users.

Comment: As of today `gcloud alpha projects create` seems to be in public alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to complete the circle here.

Google Cloud CLI tool 'gcloud' supports creating of projects without the need for the 'alpha' component installed from the version 147.0.0 (March 15, 2017) onwards.

**Official Reference Link:** https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/create

**Release Notes for v147.0.0:**
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#14700_2017-03-15

*It is mentioned under subheading of [Google Cloud Resource Manager](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#google_cloud_resource_manager_4)*

### For quick reference

#### Synopsis

```
gcloud projects create [PROJECT_ID] [--no-enable-cloud-apis] [--folder=FOLDER_ID] [--labels=[KEY=VALUE,…]] [--name=NAME] [--organization=ORGANIZATION_ID] [--set-as-default] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

#### Description

> Creates a new project with the given project ID. By default, projects are not created under a parent resource. To do so, use either the --organization or --folder flag.

#### Sample Code

```
gcloud projects create example-foo-bar-1 --name="Happy project" --labels=type=happy
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that will create a project that is editable by a user (for many reasons, such as for auditability of service accounts, you might want to create per-user projects):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -lt 3 ]; then
   echo "Usage:  ./create_projects.sh billingid project-prefix  email1 [email2 [email3 ...]]]"
   echo "   eg:  ./create_projects.sh 0X0X0X-0X0X0X-0X0X0X learnml-20170106  somebody@gmail.com someother@gmail.com"
   exit
fi
ACCOUNT_ID=$1
shift
PROJECT_PREFIX=$1
shift
EMAILS=$@
gcloud components update
gcloud components install alpha
for EMAIL in $EMAILS; do
   PROJECT_ID=$(echo "${PROJECT_PREFIX}-${EMAIL}" | sed 's/@/-/g' | sed 's/\./-/g' | cut -c 1-30)
   echo "Creating project $PROJECT_ID for $EMAIL ... "
   # Create project
   gcloud alpha projects create $PROJECT_ID
   # Add user to project
   gcloud alpha projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT_ID --format=json > iam.json.orig
   cat iam.json.orig | sed s'/"bindings": \[/"bindings": \[ \{"members": \["user:'$EMAIL'"\],"role": "roles\/editor"\},/g' > iam.json.new
   gcloud alpha projects set-iam-policy $PROJECT_ID iam.json.new
   # Set billing id of project
   gcloud alpha billing accounts projects link $PROJECT_ID --account-id=$ACCOUNT_ID
done
```

Explanation of the script is on medium: https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-automate-project-creation-using-gcloud-4e71d9a70047#.t58mss3co and a github link to the above code (I'll update it to remove the alpha when it goes beta/GA, for example) is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/blogs/gcloudprojects/create_projects.sh

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** as of 10/24/2016 @poolie says the `gcloud` command mentioned in Stephen's answer is now publicly accessable, will leave this answer here as I give some other usage suggestions.

---

I also have the problem, and was extremely discouraged by @Stephan Weinberg's remark, but I noticed when doing `gcloud init` that it asks where to put a "default" repository.  so I looked at that one's config and see that it's slightly different from what's documented.

try pushing to `https://source.developers.google.com/p/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME/r/default` instead,  it worked for me!

Comment: You must previously create the project though, but this is good to know for the initial push.